# How to include Authors@R in the manual of R package?

Tags: r, package, manual

I have the following description file as part of my R package

```
Package: blah
Title: What the Package Does (one line, title case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Jon", "Snow", email = "jon.snow@jonsnow.ac.uk", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
Depends: R (>= 3.5.1)
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.0.9000
```

I have documented my code and would like to produce a manual that accompanies it. In a previous post, people have mentioned using the command 
`R CMD Rd2pdf <work directory>` and I managed to produce a manual.

The issue is that in my manual, the bit before R topics documented does not show the authors but everything else. I have installed packages such as `devtools`, `knitr`, `roxygen2` and `testthat`. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a couple of possible answers to your question.  It's polite on this site to pick one of them and mark it as "accepted" (you'll see how if you look), or leave comments explaining why they don't quite meet your needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to include multiple authors, you have to wrap all persons in `c()`.

See the [DESCRIPTION](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) of sf for example, which looks something like this:

```
Authors@R: 
  c(person(given = "Edzer",
           family = "Pebesma",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "edzer.pebesma@uni-muenster.de",
           comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0001-8049-7069")),
    person(given = "Jeroen",
           family = "Ooms",
           role = "ctb",
           comment = c(ORCID = "0000-0002-4035-0289")),
    person(given = "Kirill",
           family = "Müller",
           role = "ctb"))
```

If there is only one author, you can simply write:

```
Author: Lax Chan
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

The `Authors@R` field is reformatted as `Author` when you build a source package.  It won't appear in your source directory, so building the manual from that won't include it.

What you need to do is to build the `tar.gz` file from the source, then create the manual from that.

Since it seems you are using command line methods, this is done by

```
R CMD build <workdir>
```

which produces something like `workdir.version.tar.gz`.  Unfortunately, `Rd2pdf` can't read this file directly, so you need two more steps.  Move to a clean directory, and run

```
tar zxvf workdir.version.tar.gz
R CMD Rd2pdf workdir
```

to produce the manual from the built DESCRIPTION file.

(I don't think it would be a disaster if you unpacked the tarball on top of the original source, but it could cause confusion later if you change the `DESCRIPTION` file.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Minor note: If you want your authorship to be "Alfred N. Other", I've found you need to use
`given=c("Alfred", "N.")`